# Derivative ParametricNDSolveValue

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions, calculus-and-analysis

i'm work with heat conduction in cylindrical coordinates, my problem is how to calculate a derivative for a parameter using ParametricNDSolveSolution.

```
L = 0.04;(*comprimento do phantom*)
b = 0.0375;(*raio do cilindro*)
kp = 0.150;(*condutividade do phantom*)
Ro = 1046.83;(*massa específica do phantom*)
Alfap = 8.05*10^-8;(*difusividade do phantom*)
Ta = 24.484;(*temperatura do meio ambiente*)
(*Betad=0.9;(*atenuação do phantom*)*)
I0 = 10000;(*intensidade do transdutor*)
Eal = 0.0048;(*espessura do alumínio*)
kal = 204;(*condutividade do alumínio*)
h1 = 5;(*coeficiente de convecção do ar para Biot 1*)
h2 = 5;(*coeficiente de convecção do ar para Biot 2*)
t5 = 300;(*tempo de duração do ultrassom*)
Tg = 24.5;(*temperatura do gel*)
\[Epsilon]1 = N[10^-5];

hef = 1/(1/h1 + Eal/kal);(*coeficiente de convecção efetivo*)
Betas = Betad*L;(*atenuação do phantom*)
Bi1 = (hef*b)/kp;(*número de Biot 1*)
Bi2 = (h2*L)/kp;(*número de Biot 2*)
Gama = L/b;(*razão de aspecto*)
I0s = (2*Betad*I0*b^2)/(kp*Ta);(*intensidade*)
Tau5 = (Alfap*t5)/b^2;(*tempo adimensional de duração ultrassom*)
Tetag = (Tg - Ta)/Ta;(*temperatura do gel adimensional*)

G[Z_, \[Tau]_] = I0s*Exp[-Betas*Z]*UnitStep[Tau5 - \[Tau]]
edp1 = D[\[Theta][R, Z, \[Tau]], \[Tau]] == 
   D[\[Theta][R, Z, \[Tau]], R, R] + 
    1/R*D[\[Theta][R, Z, \[Tau]], R] + 
    1/Gama^2*D[\[Theta][R, Z, \[Tau]], Z, Z] + G[Z, \[Tau]];

CI = (\[Theta][R, Z, \[Tau]] /. \[Tau] -> 0) == 0;
CC2 = (\[Theta][R, Z, \[Tau]] /. R -> \[Epsilon]1) == 0;
CC3 = (D[\[Theta][R, Z, \[Tau]], R] + Bi1* \[Theta][R, Z, \[Tau]]) == 
    0 /. R -> 1;
CC4 = (\[Theta][R, Z, \[Tau]] /. Z -> 0) == Tetag;
CC5 = (D[\[Theta][R, Z, \[Tau]], Z] + Bi2*\[Theta][R, Z, \[Tau]]) == 
    0 /. Z -> 1;

eqns = Flatten[{edp1, CI, CC2, CC3, CC4, CC5}]

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
  eqns, \[Theta], {R, \[Epsilon]1, 1}, {Z, 0, 1}, {\[Tau], 0, 
   0.35}, {Betad}, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
```

`Evaluate[D[sol[Betad], Betad]] /. Betad -> 0.9` This is my problem !

Any suggestions, Thanks.

Comment: are you worried about the `Warning: boundary and initial conditions are inconsistent.` ?

Comment: No, my problem is that the calculation of the derivative is taking too long

Comment: I have tested the solution without deriving the temperature profile is ok

Comment: I want to perform a sensitivity analysis

Comment: fyi `PrecisionGoal -> 2` is essentially telling the solver to accept a poor quality result.  If you remove that you get a bunch of convergence errors, but you should sort that out and not ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might take a central difference numerical derivative:

```
d0[b_, del_] := 
 d0[b, del] = (sol[b + del][x, y, z] - sol[b - del][x, y, z])/del/2
d[b_, del_][x0_, y0_, z0_] := d0[b, del] /. {x -> x0, y -> y0, z -> z0}
```

This does not seem to converge however as you reduce `del`:

```
d[.9, 0.001][.1, .1, .1]
d[.9, 0.0001][.1, .1, .1]
d[.9, 0.00001][.1, .1, .1]
d[.9, 0.000001][.1, .1, .1]
```

> -0.0914891
>
> -1.41497
>
> -1.15597
>
> 2.30509

That might be what is causing your expression to take a long time.

FWIW I first evaluated the general approaches with a 1-d function,

```
pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y'[t] == a y[t], y[0] == 1}, 
  y, {t, 0, 10}, {a}]
dp = D[pfun[a], a] /. a -> .1
del = .1;
Plot[{(pfun[.1 + del]@x - pfun[.1 - del]@x)/del/2  , dp[x]} , {x, 0, 
  10} ]
```

[image]

this *does* quickly converge if you reduce `del`

Comment: Thaks for your suggestion george2079